# If Condition on Hidden Field Value in markup (ASPX Page)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Hi I'm trying to use if condition in Markup but the Hidden Field not accessable (error: Hidden Field doesn't exists in current context).

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdpId" Value='<%# Eval("sId") %>' />

<% if (hdpId == 0) 
{ %>
--Some Markup Here
<% }
else
{ %>
--Some Markup Here
<% } %>
```

I want to create div with different position,
I have a div row with two divs,  div-detail, and div-img, If hidden field value is 0 then div-img will be place before div-detail, else div-detail will be place before div-img. One thing here to note about I'm using this if in GridView.
any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What happens to the headings of your GridView if you are going to change the order of columns inside it conditionally

Comment: headings are empty...

Answer (score 0):

Try this - obviously if you want to display images, you would need a bit more work

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource3">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Make" HeaderText="Make" SortExpression="Make" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="IsHidden" HeaderText="IsHidden" SortExpression="IsHidden" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Model/Picture">
            <ItemTemplate>                       
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# (bool)Eval("IsHidden") ? Eval("Picture") : Eval("Model") %>'></asp:Label>                       
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Model/Picture">
            <ItemTemplate>                       
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# (bool)Eval("IsHidden") ? Eval("Model") : Eval("Picture") %>'></asp:Label>                       
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>                

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Actually I want to shows the Chat Console, if msgs are from Admin the Img should be on right side, if msgs are from Client the img should be on left side... this is the actual scenario. On DataRowBound I'm checking the it but it shifts all the images to left or right, instead of just for required rows...

Comment: could you add a diagram / sketch of the outcome you are looking for? like a before / after?